# PHP foreach loop exercise

Tags: php, foreach

I'm following online PHP courses and I'm now trying to do some exercises by myself.

I've tried to write from scratch a foreach loop that should print out a simple HTML but I'm stuck on a problem.

As you can see from my code I've specified $popDiv as a variable to echo out the number of males and females in a city.

The problem is that if I do a var_dump on $popDiv it will only display the last key in the array.
array(1) { ["Females"]=> int(12) }.

Hoping someone here can help me fix but mostly understand the logic behind fixing it.

Thanks in advance!

```
    $cities = 
        [
            [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Rome',
            'Nation' => 'Italy',
            'Population' => 
                [
                    ['Males' => 20],
                    ['Females' => 1]
                ],
            'Total Population' => 20
            ],
            [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Milan',
            'Nation' => 'Italy',
            'Population' => 
                [
                    ['Males' => 20],
                    ['Females' => 50]
                ],
            'Total Population' => 70
            ],
            [
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Naples',
            'Nation' => 'Italy',
            'Population' => 
                [
                    ['Males' => 10],
                    ['Females' => 5]
                ],
            'Total Population' => 15
            ],
            [
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'Lugano',
            'Nation' => 'Swiss',
            'Population' => 
                [
                    ['Males' => 50],
                    ['Females' => 12]
                ],
            'Total Population' => 62
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($cities as $id => $city) {
            echo "<p>The city of {$city['name']} is located in {$city['Nation']} and has a population of {$city['Total Population']} inhabitants, divided between </p>";
            foreach ($city['Population'] as $popDiv)
            {
                 echo "{$popDiv['Males']} males and {$popDiv['Females']} 5 females</p>"; 
            }
        }

        var_dump($popDiv);
```

What I expect is something like this :

The city of Rome is located in Italy and has a population of 20 inhabitants, divided between 20 males and 1 female.

The city of Milan is located in Italy and has a population of 70 inhabitants, divided between 20 males and 50 females.

The city of Naples is located in Italy and has a population of 15 inhabitants, divided between 10 males and 5 females.

The city of Lugano is located in Swiss and has a population of 62 inhabitants, divided between 50 males and 12 females.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to iterate over `$city['Population']`, just use it's values directly:

```
foreach ($cities as $id => $city) {
    echo "<p>The city of {$city['name']} is located in {$city['Nation']} and has a population of {$city['Total Population']} inhabitants, divided between </p>";
    echo "{$city['Population'][0]['Males']} males and {$city['Population'][1]['Females']} females</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: If I go with something like this:

echo "<p>The city of {$city['name']} is located in {$city['Nation']} and has a population of {$city['Total Population']} inhabitants, divided between {$city['Population']['Males']} males and {$city['Population']['Females']}.</p>";


It will say that Males and Females are undefined index.

Comment: Didn't notice, see the update. `Population` is array of arrays so you need to use it like: `$city['Population'][0]['Males']`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was a simple fix, I just forgot to specify the Index of the key so now PHP knows what to echo out and that's why it was giving me an error.
Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helps to solve yopur problem.

Answer (score 0):

$popDiv is overwritten on every loop of the array, that is why it is only showing you the last loop of the array.

```
foreach ($cities as $id => $city) {
    echo "<p>The city of " . $city['name'] . " is located in " . $city['Nation'] . " and has a population of " . $city['Total Population'] . " inhabitants, divided between " . $city['Population'][0]['Males'] . " males and " . $city['Population'][0]['Females'] . " 5 females</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I'm getting an error for Undefined Index of Males / Females.

Comment: Try it now - I changed $city['Population']['Males'] to $city['Population'][0]['Males']